# Laravel Vue POST to api uses web route instead of api route

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, routes

I'm building a MPA with Laravel and Vue.js, and I made a form which posts to an api route. It worked when I was on my homepage, but now I moved it to a subpage (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/muziek`) and when I try to submit it, I keep getting the `The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.` warning, so I think it uses the `web.php`-routes instead of the `api.php`-routes.

I have this as my method to post to my internal Laravel API:

```
addMusicItem() {
        if (this.item.name != '') {
            axios.post('/api/record/store', {
                record: this.item
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status == 201) {
                    this.item.name = "";
                }

            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
    }
```

with my `api.php`-routing like this:

```
Route::get('/records', [MusicItemController::class, 'index']);
Route::prefix('/record')->group(function(){
   Route::post('/store', [MusicItemController::class, 'store'])->name('music.store');
   Route::put('/{id}', [MusicItemController::class, 'update']);
   Route::delete('/{id}', [MusicItemController::class, 'destroy']);
});
```

Does someone have an idea what is going on? I tried to change the `RouteServiceProvider` but that didn't work either. :/

Comment: You can at least verify which route it is posting to by checking your network tab in your dev tools. Check the request header to see which path is being used, so you can confirm if it’s posting to web or api routes.

Comment: Quick question, why are you defining each stuff when you can just do `Route::apiResource('records', MusicItemController::class);` (more info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#api-resource-routes))

Answer (score 0):

Change Your routes to this :

```
Route::prefix('/record')->group(function(){
   Route::post('/store', [MusicItemController::class, 'store'])->name('music.store');
   Route::put('/{id}', [MusicItemController::class, 'update']);
   Route::delete('/{id}', [MusicItemController::class, 'destroy']);
});
Route::get('/records', [MusicItemController::class, 'index']);
```